# Open git bash in current directory

Tags: windows, windows-10, bash, git

Previously when I was in a directory, I clicked 'git bash here' and it would open in that directory. Now it opens my home directory. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you changed the location of Git?

Comment: Hi Joeri. For me, _git bash here_ works as expected. I need to be able to reproduce that to help you - something is preventing the path to be used by git bash...

Comment: *git bash here* also works as expected for me.  I just reinstalled from package `Git-2.33.1-64-bit.exe` and added the option (I normally use WSL bash so I don't need this option).  Have you tried a fresh installation with the package I just mentioned?

Comment: Try to uninstall and re-install Git.

Comment: Yes, I already reinstalled git. Unfortunately did this not fix it. I don't know what is preventing the path to be used @LeonardoAlvesMachado

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yes, I've tried a fresh install.. Any other options?

Comment: @harrymc Already did. No succes :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem.  It turns out that the ".bashrc" file was installed at sometime in the past (maybe WSL, I'm thinking). Anyway, ".bashrc" had the following command in it: "cd ~".  Removed that command and voila!

To Fix:

- start a shell or navigate via File Explorer.
  (if you start a shell your will already be in your home dir.  This is, of course, the problem you are trying to resolve.)
- edit .bashrc with your favorite text editor.
- eliminate the offending command "cd ~" and save your work.
- close out your shell and restart a new shell so the newly edited .bashrc file will take affect

- your shell should now put you in the directory as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If your Git context menu is incorrect in the registry, below are the
registry modifications for adding this entry, as taken from the post
[How to add a "open git-bash here..." context menu to the windows explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386657/how-to-add-a-open-git-bash-here-context-menu-to-the-windows-explorer)

Check that your registry entries are similar, or just put the following
contents in a `.reg` file and launch it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Open files
; Default Git-Bash Location C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open Git Bash]
@="Open Git Bash"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open Git Bash\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe\" \"--cd=%1\""

; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\bash]
@="Open Git Bash"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\bash\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe\" \"--cd=%1\""

; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\bash]
@="Open Git Bash"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\bash\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe\" \"--cd=%v.\""
```

This adds "Open Git Bash" to the context menu, rather than "git bash here",
but apart from this, the registry modifications should be nearly
identical to what yours should be.

Comment: After doing the above, if it still doesn't work (it should work), use the Process Explorer to show us the command line for gitbash.exe after it fires up.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I've followed the instructions. The problem is no that the ''git here'' isn't in the context menu. That works perfectly fine. The problem is that when I execute that, it won't start in that directory. It starts all the way in my home directory. What is so frustrating...

Comment: https://ibb.co/mtQWMR8

Comment: If the `--cd` argument of `git-bash` is not working for you, check `.bashrc` or its equivalent on Windows, to see if the script does not contain a line like "cd $GIT_HOME".